# Angular2 - Class property is undefined even though it is being set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having the following, very simple angular2 Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DrawingService {
    private _draw:Draw;

    constructor(private mapSvc:MapService) {}

    initialize(geometry: GeometryType):void {
        this._draw = new Draw(this.mapSvc.getMap());
        this._draw.on("draw-end", this.addGraphic);
        this._draw.activate(geometry);
    }


    addGraphic(evt):void {
        this._draw.deactivate();
    }
}
```

In `initialize`, I'm setting the method `addGraphic` as the callback. Now the problem is, that within the `addGraphic` method execution, `this._draw` is undefined.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Where is `initialize(geomotry)` being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a method reference like

```
   this._draw.on("draw-end", this.addGraphic);
```

the reference to `this` points to the caller function.

If you use instead

```
   this._draw.on("draw-end", this.addGraphic.bind(this));
```

it should work as expected.

Alternatively you can also use arrow functions but this requires to repeat the parameters (if there need any to be passed).

```
   this._draw.on("draw-end", (param) => this.addGraphic(param));
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to ngOnInit() instead of the constructor.  You'll have to implement OnInit.